# udisks-daemon eating up all my memory

Tags: debian, memory, hard-drive, daemon, udev

I'm operating a little storage server on debian, over the past months I've noticed the process **udisks-daemon** eating up almost all available memory.

Is this just really aggressive caching or a memory leak?

```
uname -a
Linux Proto 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

free -m
              total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7999       7390        608          0        317        368
-/+ buffers/cache:       6704       1294
Swap:        15621      15621          0

vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd    free   buff   cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0 15996920 621216 325464 378660    0    1   327   138    1    0  3  1 96  0

ps axo pid,args,pmem,rss,vsz --sort -pmem,-rss,-vsz | head -n 5
  PID COMMAND                     %MEM   RSS    VSZ
12289 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daem 74.1 6072704 21972744
11899 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbo  0.2 21068 124840
12280 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-dae  0.2 17512 301856
12310 update-notifier              0.1 13692 252596
```

Comment: This does not seems to be aggressive caching. It seems to be a bug as per the Ubuntu/Debian forums for excessive resource usage by `udisk-daemon`.

Comment: Can you point me to some threads at the forums? My google search didnt yield any results.

Comment: you might check this out [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/587044)
In your case it is using memory.

Comment: I had this problem and found this related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/1053898

Answer (score 0):

just restart udisks2 service.

```bash
sudo service udisks2 restart
```